# tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, backup

Here is the script which i am using for backups

```
#!/bin/bash

src_dir=/home/ubuntu/scripts
tgt_dir=/home/ubuntu/backups

curr_timestamp=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
backup_file=$tgt_dir/$curr_timestamp.tgz
echo "Taking backup on $curr_timestamp"
echo "$backup_file"

#tar -cf back_file.tar ./*
tar czf  $backup_file --absolute-names $scripts
echo "Backup complete"
```

It is not working for me and getting an error

```
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Please edit your question and format your script so that it is presented correctly. It is distorted now and it's not clear how the real code looks like.

Comment: See if this helps: https://superuser.com/questions/448623/how-to-get-an-empty-tar-archive

Answer (score 5):

`$scripts` is empty if these lines are all there is